# Substitute strings (filename) in given directory in Perl

Tags: perl, substitution

I have a entire directory path with filename in a scalar variable. I want to extract some sort of string from a filename (ab%ABpeterfra).

Script below:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $file = "/this/is/my/directory/ab%ABpeterfra";
print "file:$file\n";

my @array = split('%', $file); print $array[1]."\n"; 

my $final = substr($array[1], 2);

print "final:$final\n"; #peterfra
```

Here I am getting the desired result, i.e., peterfra.

But Is there any way I can use Perl Substitution and achieve the same result or any better way to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent using the substitution operator would be

```perl
my $final = $file =~ s/^[^%]*%..//sr;   # $file if no match
```

But rather than taking away what I don't want, I prefer to find what I do want.

The equivalent using the match operator would be

```perl
my ($final) = $file =~ /%..(.*)/s;      # undef if no match
```

Comment: These are slightly different than the original code when there are two `%`.